# Image not loading in JS when referenced through switch case

Tags: html, image, switch-statement, src

So I have a quiz where based on a sum value an image with your character will be appended to the paragraph showing the result, my problem is the images will not load in. I know the code works but until the console.log(sum) since it is logged when loading the file in the browser.

I'll post my code below(this is Javascript and html)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <h1>Which Star Wars Character Are You?</h1>
  <form>
    What color is your Lightsaber?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Red</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">Blue</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Purple</label>
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    With which organization would you most likely aligned?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Empire</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">Rebel Alliance</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Neither</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Do you submit to the Emperor's will?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Yes</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">No</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Maybe</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Would you help a friend if it meant being sealed in carbonite?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">No of course not</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">Yes, I want to save my friends</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Depends on the friend</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Do you like Wookies?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Only as a tool to crush my enemies</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">Yes I consider the creatures as friends</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">I've met a few good Wookies in my time, a few hostile ones     too</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Would you ever construct a Droid Army to usurp the Empire's power?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">No, the Empire must be upheld, always</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">No, using an Army of Droids would make us just as bad</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Yes, absolutely</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Jar Jar Binks yay or nay?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Yay</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">My father liked Jar Jar</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Nay, a thousand times, Nay</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Have you seen the Mr. Plinkett Star Wars Reviews?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">No</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">I've heard of them</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">Yes, he is right on all points raised</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Would you build a DeathStar or something like it to assert dominance over   the Galaxy?
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">Yes, maybe even 2 times</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">No, the DeathStar is a war machine that must be destroyed</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">I would possible use such a machine or vessel for my goals</label> 
    </blockquote>
  </form>
  <form>
    Did you like/know of KOTOR 1 or 2
    <blockquote>
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label  for="red">No</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label     for="blue">Yes</label> 
      <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">I liked KOTO2 but KOTOR 1 had a lame ending.</label> 
    </blockquote>
    <br><br><input type="button" id="qButton" value="Choose">
  </form>
  <p id="QuestionParagraph"></p>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.house {
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function getButton() {
    var button = document.getElementById('qButton');
    button.onclick = getResult;
}

function getResult() {

    var sum = 0;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('lightsaber');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
            console.log(sum);
            showChar(sum);
        }
    }
}

function showChar(sum) {

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.className = 'lightsaber';
    var source = document.getElementById('QuestionParagraph');

    switch (sum) {
        case (sum <= 12):
            image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_sly.jpg';
            break;
        case (13 <= sum <= 17):
            image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_01-5B1-5D.jpg';
            break;
        case (18 <= sum <= 30):
            image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_huf.jpg';
            break;
        default:
            image.src = '';
            source.appendChild(image);
    }
}

window.onload = getButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a switch (instead of an if-else construct), replace the condition `sum` by `true`. Also, your `source.appendChild` is inside the switch, so it will be executed only when the switch case falls to default. I guess what you want is for it to be *always* executed, so put it outside the switch.

Example:

```
switch(true){
    case (sum<=12):
        image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_sly.jpg';
        break;
    case (13<=sum<=17):
        image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_01-5B1-5D.jpg';
        break;
    case (18<=sum<=30):
        image.src = 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_huf.jpg';
        break;
    default:
        image.src = '';
}
source.appendChild(image);
```

Finally, by always creating the image, you will potentially end up with multiple image results. To avoid this, you could use this code at the beginning of `showChar`:

```
var image = document.getElementById('imgResult');
if (!image) {
  image = document.createElement('img');
  image.id = "imgResult";
  image.className = 'lightsaber';
}
```

Working versions:

- https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/p9eh18d0/ (multiple images possible
- https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/p9eh18d0/1/ (with the fix proposed above)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you change to `if/then/else` and do it for example like below sample snippet.

By start using objects like the `var img = {...}`, you will be able to make your solution more dynamic, where you also can handle your questions and answer in a similar way.

```js
var qp = document.getElementById('QuestionParagraph');
var img = {
            12: 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_sly.jpg',
            17: 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_01-5B1-5D.jpg',
            30: 'http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/icons/shield_huf.jpg'
          }

function getButton() {
    var button = document.getElementById('qButton');
    button.onclick = getResult;
}

function getResult(){
    var sum = 0;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('lightsaber');
    for (i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
        console.log(sum);
        showChar(sum);
        }
    }       
}

function appendImage(src,trg){    
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.className = 'lightsaber';
  image.src = src;
  trg.appendChild(image);
}

function showChar(sum){
  if (sum <= 12) {
    appendImage(img[12],qp);
  } else if (sum <= 17) {
    appendImage(img[17],qp);
  } else if (sum <= 30) {
    appendImage(img[30],qp);
  }
}

window.onload = getButton;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #06f;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.house {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Which Star Wars Character Are You?</h1>
<form>
What color is your Lightsaber?
<blockquote>
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Red</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label    for="blue">Blue</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">Purple</label>
</blockquote>   
</form>

<form>
With which organization would you most likely aligned?
<blockquote>



    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Empire</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label    for="blue">Rebel Alliance</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label  for="purple">Neither</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Do you submit to the Emperor's will?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Yes</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label   for="blue">No</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">Maybe</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Would you help a friend if it meant being sealed in carbonite?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">No of course not</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label   for="blue">Yes, I want to save my friends</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">Depends on the friend</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Do you like Wookies?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Only as a tool to crush my enemies</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label   for="blue">Yes I consider the creatures as friends</label> 
  <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">I've met a few good Wookies in my time, a few hostile ones     too</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Would you ever construct a Droid Army to usurp the Empire's power?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">No, the Empire must be upheld, always</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label   for="blue">No, using an Army of Droids would make us just as bad</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label  for="purple">Yes, absolutely</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Jar Jar Binks yay or nay?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Yay</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label    for="blue">My father liked Jar Jar</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">Nay, a thousand times, Nay</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Have you seen the Mr. Plinkett Star Wars Reviews?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">No</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label    for="blue">I've heard of them</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">Yes, he is right on all points raised</label> 
</blockquote>   
    </form>

<form>
Would you build a DeathStar or something like it to assert dominance over   the Galaxy?
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">Yes, maybe even 2 times</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label   for="blue">No, the DeathStar is a war machine that must be destroyed</label> 
    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label     for="purple">I would possible use such a machine or vessel for my goals</label> 
</blockquote>
    </form>

<form>
Did you like/know of KOTOR 1 or 2
<blockquote>


    <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="red" value="1"> <label    for="red">No</label> 
   <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="blue" value="2"> <label    for="blue">Yes</label> 
  <br><input type="radio" name="lightsaber" id="purple" value="3"> <label   for="purple">I liked KOTO2 but KOTOR 1 had a lame ending.</label> 
</blockquote>



<br><br><input type="button" id="qButton" value="Choose">
</form>
<p id="QuestionParagraph"></p>
```

Comment: thanks this works my only problem is the pictures are printing at each sum increment and I need it to just show the result once at the end. I'm thinking this is where having the same name for each input is making things difficult.